# Splitting pdf with varying page lengths

Tags: c#, ruby, perl, pdf, pypdf

I have a number of pdfs that are merged from various other pdfs of varying length.

That gives a lot of problems when you have to examine the pdf to find out where to split it, open Adobe and then split the document up into the 10-20 different documents.

Is there a way to detect where the pdfs have been merged and possibly split them automatically. Preferably in python using PyPDF2, but any language would do. I'm just interested in getting something that works.

Comment: how do those partial documents differ? How had they been merged? In which programming language using which pdf library do you plan to implement your pdf splitter?

Comment: They are made by varying products. A quick test showed BancTec? and Adobe. But they are images, text and more. Can't differentiate them that way.
I would prefer to make the splitter in python and PyPDF2

Comment: If the cross-reference tables (xref) were never consolidated, it might be possible but again, it depends on how they were assembled. You could use the xref tables to basically undo the merge by stripping off the last merged file all the way back to the first file. If I could see an example PDF, I could tell for sure.

Comment: @Rasmus *"I would prefer to make the splitter in python and PyPDF2"* - please mention this in your question and tag it accordingly.

Comment: @mkl I have tagged them and revised the question

Comment: @joelgeraci I have an example document for you. Where should i send it to?

Comment: If possible, share example documents not individually but to all readers of your question, e.g. by creating a public share with them in dropbox or google drive and posting the URL here.

Comment: As @mkl commented, any publicly addressable URL will be fine. It would also help to know if all of the PDFs were merged using the same application and in the same manner.

Comment: @joelgeraci and mkl. The documents we work with are classified. But I have uploaded a similar document which is public. The state decided to 'digitize' all the documents regarding properties, so they decided to scann all the documents and merge them into 1 huge pdf. It is up to the rest of us to seperate the documents when we need them. A case of digitalization gone wrong :-)
But as such I cannot guarantee which program is used. But most seem to be made by BancTec..

I have uploaded a public document to my gdrive:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k1yKTNsuGCF11u0DoQ8UtCKm2umaEPom

Comment: Well... unfortunately, I'm only seeing one cross-reference table. I'm not seeing any metadata that you might be able to use in the images either. I'm not sure if you'll ever be able to burst these into the separate files based on the content of the pages.

Comment: Damn. I really hoped there would be a way. Thank you for trying!